# Correct way to pass in a SQL function as a value

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I want to update a record's DateUpdated field each time the user updates the record.

I thought I should do it like this:

```
<cfquery>
UPDATE
dbo.MyTable
SET DateUpdated = <cfqueryparam value="GetDate()" />
</cfquery>
```

I don't know if this correct. There's no `cfsqltype` attribute value for a function. In which case, do I just do this

```
<cfquery>
    UPDATE
    dbo.MyTable
    SET DateUpdated = GetDate()
</cfquery>
```

Comment: This will update every row in the table, BTW

Comment: @JamesAMohler you're right, its just example code

Comment: You are confusing CF and database functions. Expressions within the cfqueryparam are evaluated by the CF server *first*. CF then sends the evaluated string of SQL on to your database for processing. Since `getDate()` is a SQL Server function, CF knows nothing about it. Meaning you cannot use it inside cfqueryparam. You can only use *CF* functions, such as `now()` (cont'd)

Comment: Using a function makes no difference. The `cfsqltype` applies to the single value *returned* by the function. If the function returns a datetime object (like `now()` does), you use `cf_sql_timestamp` (date and time) OR `cf_sql_date` (date only) depending on whether or not you wish to include the time portion.  However, as Carl pointed out, if you can also use the database function `getDate()` instead. In which case you do not need cfqueryparam at all.

Comment: RE: *Correct way to pass in a SQL function as a value* To clarify and answer your question, a **database** function is not a "value" . It is a sql command that must be evaluated by your database.  Wrapping it in cfqueryparam prevents that from happening. So the answer is: do not use cfqueryparam on **database** functions. Your second example is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one won't work because you parameterized the SQL function name, so it will pass "GetDate()" as a literal string. However, if you replaced "GetDate()" with "#Now()#" it should work, since you are passing the value from a ColdFusion function.

The second one should work as-is though.

Comment: I tried using Now() but it doesn't supply the time. But SQL's own GetDate() does

Comment: Yes it does. See my comments above.

Comment: Right understood. I was using Now() with cf_sql_date and hence the time part never got written!